# "Putative" vs. "surrogate"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, connotation, collocation

How similar or different is "putative" to "surrogate"? The term "surrogate father" is common, "putative father" is fairly so, too. But what may be the difference in connotation?

Comment: The words have very different meanings. Did you look them up in a dictionary? I don't really see where your confusion comes from, could you explain what you did not understand from the definitions?

Comment: Rather than not understand the definitions, I fail to see how they differ.. But as you say they are different..

Comment: I get it now.. putative is in the shadows of "alleged".. negative connotation?

Comment: Putative is basically _possible_ or _potential_ while surrogate is _replacement_. The words are really not similar at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are hardly alike at all.

a **putative** father is a man who is said to be the biological father of a child without that fact being completely sure.

While it does not have to have a negative connotation, in many cases it can have them, because using the word questions the actual fatherhood. There are plenty of situations in which that *doubt* will be perceived as negative, although in some (clinical?) situations, it is not completely neutral.

I would not, however, expect a man to proudly go around and claim to be a child's putative father.

A **surrogate** father can roughly mean three things, non of them having normally negative connotations:

- A man who is not the father of a child but fulfils the father role for it.
- A man who donated his sperm for a child to be conceived, but does not play the father role.
- A man who became a father through the use of a surrogate mother.

For these three, and especially the 3rd definition, see [here](http://www.livestrong.com/article/77414-surrogate-father/). I have not heard it often used in that sense, but it seems to be in use.

Contrary to *putative*, there is no doubt or uncertainty involved in the case of a surrogate father.

Comment: I am struck by the oddness of the fact that your first two definitions for *surrogate father* are based on criteria that are precisely opposite in each case. (That crazy old English, eh?  :)

Comment: In one case he acts as a surrogate by filling another man's genetic role, in the other he acts as a surrogate by filling another man's social role. Not entirely opposite.

Comment: But I think the definition above of putative father is not entirely right. The putative father is the man regarded as the father, and since we are qualifying his fatherhood that way, we imply his actual fatherhood is questionable. It has nothing to do with his legal relationship with the mother though.

Comment: I really don't see how marriage is relevant here. Yes, in certain conservative societies, having a child out of wedlock is still frowned upon, but _putative_ has nothing to do with the parent's legal relationship, only with the relationship between the father and child.

Comment: @Neil, you are right. There are two possibilities for the putative father indeed. The biological father without the "proper" relationship, as I mentioned, but I guess it can also be the guy who socially is supposed to be the father, though there may be suspicions about the actual biological part.

Comment: @terdon: I did certainly not mean that marriage is the only acceptable social arrangement that would be relevant here. _Putative_ does have the connotation that something untoward has happened between the mother of the child and someone else than the socially expected father of her children.

Comment: To my mind _putative_ just means the man _might_ be the father or claims to be the father in some way but that has not been demonstrated. I just don't see how the social contract comes into it. I can be the _putative father_ of my wife's child if I have doubts about who sired him/her.

Comment: @terdon Which would make you fit into my second definition that I just added :) And if you suspect the milkman could be the one that sired the child, the milkman could also be a putative father of the same child. It depends on which part of the situation you focus on: the "legitimate but possibly not biological father" or the "illegitimate but possibly biological father". Please note that I use "legitimate" here in the loosest of possible meanings, to be understood to fit the wide variety of current social contracts governing parenthood and relationships :)

Comment: @oerkelens "Biological father without the proper relationship" conflates 2 possible meanings of "fatherhood" (biological vs legal/socal) and ends up saying something definite about what the latter relationship actually is (something which *putative* cannot do). Your two meanings of "putative father" would have to be "one said to have the legal/social status of fatherhood" and "one said to have the biological relationship of fatherhood".

Comment: @Rupe: I think I cover those two. But without the social complications, no-one would use the word _putative_. If a husband is the _putative_ father of his wife's child, then there is the clear implication that a social contract has been violated. If the biological father is not the husband, but there is no "scandal", no-one will call the husband the _putative_ father.

Comment: @oerkelens "If a husband is the putative father of his wife's child, then there is the clear implication that a social contract has been violated." I couldn't disagree with this more and I find it a little disturbing that you're trying to make such an innocent word imply so much. I'm not sure how else to try to explain it other than that "putative" only means "regarded as" and one of the things that's useful about it is the fact that it is *non-judgemental* (in comparison for example with "alleged father")

Comment: @Rupe: I go with terdon on this: "I can be the putative father of my wife's child if I have doubts about who sired him/her". That is also what I included in my answer. Now, whether or not you consider it judgemental or not, the mere implication that there may be a doubt as to whether the husband sired the baby _does_ in the vast majority of modern societies imply a breach of social contract.

Comment: Putative addresses what is said; if someone is a putative father, they are said to be the father (whether or not that is true). It most commonly occurs in usage where the parentage is in doubt, but that is because it is redundant in the case of what is said and what is true being the same. Surrogate addresses a substitution for another in some capacity. As identified already, this could be genetic, social etc.

Comment: @oerkelens That's right, I see no negative connotation whatsoever. Generally speaking, one tends to assume that a married couple are the biological parents of the children they have the legal/social parenthood relationship with, even when one has no knowledge of the conception. So in my mind, most husbands are the putative biological fathers of their children. In some medical context where the genetics is important but not-yet-known then I can well imagine making a totally non-judgemental list which pairs children with their "putative fathers".

Comment: @Rupe: I can see there are such situations. However, be it right or not, there are plenty of situations where addressing someone as the putative father of their child will not be taken lightly by the people involved - if only because there are only so many (very few) valid reasons to imply _doubt_ about the fatherhood. That _doubt_ carries a negative connotation in many cases - and that is the main difference with the surrogate: there _is_ no doubt.

Comment: @oerkelens I will concede that if someone refers to *themselves* as the putative father of their own children then it's hard not to get a negative connotation (unless for example they were explicitly on the kind of list I mention in my previous comment: "Technically I'm only a *putative father*, until they do the DNA test and move me onto the *potential donors* list")

Comment: Well as others have pointed out, the main difference with *surrogate* is that it means something completely different. And sure, it is easy to imagine contexts where using the phrase "putative father" would raise eyebrows. But the negativity would not contained in the meaning of the word "putative". You're still conflating 2 meanings of "father" in order to create the negativity.

Comment: @Rupe I have edited out (I think) the unnecessary family-ties and superfluous negativity.

Comment: I still think you're complicating things rather a lot. I disagree with your definition of "putative father" in that it should omit that last bit "without that fact being completely sure". Really don't like your answer to this, sorry.

Comment: @Rupe If the fact is completely sure, outside specific hospital situations, why would someone use the word _putative_? You may or may not like peoples' aversion to having their fatherhood questioned, but I am afraid it is beyond you and me to change that.

Comment: I don't believe it questions it, that's the point. It asserts that they are regarded as the father, without questioning it. That's how it differs from eg "alleged father".

Comment: Can I also ask for a reference for your 3rd use of "surrogate". I don't think that "A man who became a father through the use of a surrogate mother" would be called a "surrogate father" by virtue of that fact.

Comment: @Rupe If there is no question, there is no reason to mention it at all. Hence, mentioning it will _at the very least_ imply the question. I added a reference for surrogate (3). That man would, by the way, normally be the biological father beyond a doubt, and there would be no reason to "assert" him as the father to the point of naming it. Just like the majority of fathers are never called _putative_ and would likely object to being called that.

Comment: @ Erik Kowal yeah the first two definitions of surrogate father are like 1.0 and 0,1 one lines of code overlapping the other.. English is said to be a funny language..